# TestGameExamination

Tags: strategy, optimization

You are given 10 sets of papers with 10 questions each. Answer to each question is from 1 to 4. You somehow get your hands on the answer sheets and able to memorize each answer (Answer sheets only contain set number and 10 answers from 1 to 4). Although on the exam day, you don't know which set you have in hand. What strategy should you opt in order to maximize the minimal possible score you can get? (Assuming that you cannot answer any question based on your knowledge related to the subject.)

Comment: @OmicronZed Word for word. Unfortunately as the other has no answer I can't mark it as duplicate. Instead I have voted to close as lacking attribution. Afor, please tell us where this question comes from - we have an anti-plagiarism policy on Puzzling that means all unoriginal puzzles need to have their source listed, to give credit to the original creator. Thanks!